# Creating new variables automatically and conditionally onto existing data set or data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I have 2 data frames D1 & G1 and want to create new variables onto D1 according to values in G1. I am new to R so below I show how I am currently doing it and would like a more efficient way as I know my method below is very basic.

## Code to produce df 'D1'

```
customer <-c("071","072","073","074","075")
grp1 <-c(1,0,0,0,0)
grp2 <-c(1,0,0,0,0)
grp3 <-c(0,1,1,0,0)
grp4 <-c(0,0,1,1,0)
grp5 <-c(0,0,0,0,1)
D1 <- data.frame(customer,grp1,grp2,grp3,grp4,grp5)

D1

  customer grp1 grp2 grp3 grp4 grp5
1  071     1    1    0    0    0
2  072     0    0    1    0    0
3  073     0    0    1    1    0
4  074     0    0    0    1    0
5  075     0    0    0    0    1
```

## Code to produce df 'G1'

```
Cluster <- c(1,1,2,2,3)
groupname <-c("grp1","grp2","grp3","grp4","grp5")
G1 <- data.frame(Cluster,groupname)

G1

  Cluster groupname
1       1      grp1
2       1      grp2
3       2      grp3
4       2      grp4
5       3      grp5
```

## Question for Desired Output:

need to create new variables cluster1:3 (like below) onto df 'D1' by summing the variables grp1:grp5 according to the groupnames which fall into each cluster on df 'G1' 
Example: from the df 'G1' we can see that cluster1 = (grp1+grp2), therefore on df 'D1' customer 071 has a value of 2 for cluster1.

```
  customer grp1 grp2 grp3 grp4 grp5 cluster1 cluster2 cluster3
1      071    1    1    0    0    0        2        0        0
2      072    0    0    1    0    0        0        1        0
3      073    0    0    1    1    0        0        2        0
4      074    0    0    0    1    0        0        1        0
5      075    0    0    0    0    1        0        0        1
```

currently I have been applying the formulae for each cluster using the following

```
D1$cluster1 <- with (D1, grp1+grp2)
D1$cluster2 <- with (D1, grp3+grp4)
D1$cluster3 <- with (D1, grp5)
```

but in reality my G1 table has 60 unique cluster values so I need a better and more automatic way to do it instead of having 60 lines of code and also because the 'groupnames'  which fall into each cluster can change for a different data set so by having an automatic way would be better to use in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, using `split` on the `G1$groupname` variable to subset the `D1` columns and return a sum of each row:

```
cbind(D1,
 lapply(split(as.character(G1$groupname),paste0("Cluster",G1$Cluster)),
   function(x) rowSums(D1[x]) ) 
)

#  customer grp1 grp2 grp3 grp4 grp5 Cluster1 Cluster2 Cluster3
#1      071    1    1    0    0    0        2        0        0
#2      072    0    0    1    0    0        0        1        0
#3      073    0    0    1    1    0        0        2        0
#4      074    0    0    0    1    0        0        1        0
#5      075    0    0    0    0    1        0        0        1
```

Comment: Thanks to "AKRUN" & "THELATEMAIL'::: Thanks for this solution. Worked brilliantly.

Comment: To "akrun" & "thelatemail" - I used the solution from "thelatemail" as  dplyr and tidyr had a dependency on running on R v3.1.1 - as I was using 3.1 on Linux I got an error message when trying install and call library tidyr. However I tried both solution on 3.1.1 on windows and they worked brilliantly.  Really appreciate your efforts :-) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)

 res <- cbind(D1,
 left_join(D1%>%
 gather(groupname, Val, grp1:grp5) ,G1, by="groupname")%>%
 mutate(Cluster=paste0("Cluster",Cluster)) %>%
 group_by(customer, Cluster)%>% summarize(Val=sum(Val)) %>% 
 spread(Cluster, Val) %>% 
 select(-customer))

 res
 #     customer grp1 grp2 grp3 grp4 grp5 Cluster1 Cluster2 Cluster3
 #1      071    1    1    0    0    0        2        0        0
 #2      072    0    0    1    0    0        0        1        0
 #3      073    0    0    1    1    0        0        2        0
 #4      074    0    0    0    1    0        0        1        0
 #5      075    0    0    0    0    1        0        0        1
```